# R glm.nb Error in x[good, , drop = FALSE] : (subscript) logical subscript too long

Tags: r, glm

I am fighting with some data and I get an error and I can't figure why...

```
initial <-read.table....
library(Mass)
```

**All is fine until:**

```
glm.percent <- glm.nb(cbind(Count, Rest)~ Plasmid+Region*Plasmid, data=initial)

Error in x[good, , drop = FALSE] : (subscript) logical subscript too long
```

So for a bit more background. I want to compare the proportion of cells in 6 tissue layers. No I know I have to use integers in R for the negative binomial and I read that I have to use cbind to link my possitive number of counts to my negative number of counts. So this is what I have done above. I read previously that this error might be due to lacking data point, but all is fine. Does anyone have any useful ideas?

```
'data.frame':   54 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ Plasmid: Factor w/ 2 levels "CTR","EXP": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ Region : Factor w/ 6 levels "L0","L1","L2+3",..: 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 ...
 $ Count  : int  0 3 34 12 83 361 426 185 402 565 ...
 $ Rest   : int  464 592 306 482 791 103 169 155 92 309 ...
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're confused about the difference between a binomial and a negative binomial model; this is a common confusion.  For proportions, you should use a binomial (not a negative binomial) model ...

```
model <- glm(cbind(Count, Rest)~ Region*Plasmid, 
             family=binomial, data=initial)
```

or

```
initial <- transform(initial,
                     total=Rest+Count,
                     prop=Count/(Rest+Count))
model <- glm(prop ~ Region*Plasmid, weights=total,
             family=binomial, data=initial)
```

Comment: Thank you. I used a quasibinomial in the end as it seemed to be giving me the least amount of complaints